# »Der Islam gehört zu Deutschland« - "to" or "in"?

Tags: translation, preposition, german-to-english

I'm wondering exactly how native German speakers would translate the [infamous statement](http://www.zeit.de/2015/09/christian-wullf-angela-merkel-islam-deutschland):

> Der Islam gehört zu Deutschland

and its equally infamous counterpart:

> Der Islam gehört nicht zu Deutschland

I've read articles containing these two statements for many months now, and always translated them in my mind as:

> Islam belongs ***to*** Germany

or

> Islam does not belong ***to*** Germany

My (probably not surprising) assumption was that "zu" is best translated here as "to".

But I was surprised yesterday when I saw [a new article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/10/03/the-new-star-of-germanys-far-right) in the American magazine *The New Yorker* which translated the latter statement as:

> Islam does not belong ***in*** Germany

When "zu" is translated to English as "in", the sentence takes on a significantly different meaning. And so now I am very curious to see what native German speakers think.

So my questions are:

1. How exactly would you translate:

   > Der Islam gehört zu Deutschland
2. And, also, regardless of how you translate this sentence, can you please also rate the two English translations I have provided against each other?

   Do you find my two translations as equally valid translations, or is one a slightly worse translation, a significantly worse translation, or even a wrong translation?

---

P.S. Hopefully, it goes without saying that I am not asking for anyone's political opinion on the topic at hand. This is an important sentance that has been constantly cited and debated in German media for years (as evidenced by the *Zeit* story linked above), and understanding its correct meaning is necessary for understanding a very important topic.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question in such a way that it can be answered without a detailed knowledge of the use of the English verb "to belong"?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure I can. I don't see how such a change would even be possible. Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: I would have personally gone for the *New Yorker* translation as it cleverly circumvents the issue: since an abstract concept like religion cannot be owned, *in* avoids the ambiguity with *belong to* and more closely relates to the sense of "being part of" that is normally conveyed by *gehören zu*

Comment: @ardila: No. As I showed in my answer, 'belong in' has a completely different meaning an can not be used to express 'being part of'.

Comment: I'm a German native speaker, but I have no idea how to correctly translate this in a foreign language like English. The question you asked is NOT about German language, but about English language and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: @jarnbjo I didn't claim that they meant the same thing, merely that I, personally, found the translation fitting. Such a shift in meaning is a translator's prerogative after all :)

Comment: Are you sure you know the meaning of the English word "infamous"?

Comment: @fdb Yes. The evidence that `infamous` is a fitting description in this context is linked within my question. The first hyperlink in my question points to a March 2015 article in *Die Zeit* about this sentence. (http://www.zeit.de/2015/09/christian-wullf-angela-merkel-islam-deutschland) In the second paragraph of that article, it is reported that former Bundespräsident Wulff believes that this sentence contributed to his ouster from office in 2012. Quote: *Wulff glaubt, dass der Satz zu seinem Sturz beigetragen habe, weil einige Medien ihn nicht gemocht und eine Kampagne entfacht hätten.*

Comment: Der Satz wird schon im Deutschen sehr unterschiedlich interpretiert, wobei sich die leidenschaftliche Gewissheit, was er bedeuten muss umgekehrt proportional zur Fähigkeit und Bereitschaft verhält, die Bedeutung analytisch darzulegen. Ob es eine Zustandsbeschreibung sein soll, oder eine programmatische Aussage für die Zukunft, schon darüber gehen die Meinungen auseinander. Vor einer Übersetzung wäre daher zu klären, was mit dem Satz überhaupt gemeint ist. Man könnte freilich auch versuchen die Mehrdeutigkeit in die Übersetzung zu retten.

Comment: Bin etwas überrascht, dass die Frage geschlossen wurde, mit dem Argument, dass es hier nicht um Deutsch geht. So wie ich die Frage verstehe, möchte OP wissen, wie *genau* der deutsche Satz gemeint/zu verstehen ist und benutzt dazu die engl. Übersetzung als Werkzeug. Im Übrigen bittet er im ersten Satz explizit um die Meinung deutscher Muttersprachler. Meines Erachtens on topic.

Comment: @Mac Kann schon sein, dass das die Intention der Frage ist, aber dann müsste sie anders gestellt werden. Zumindest sollte der OP dann in seinen Worten erklären, was seiner Meinung es für einen Unterschied macht, wenn man in der englischen Version _to_ oder _in_ benutzt. In der jetzigen Form: leave closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO, the issue is not the preposition, but to use 'belong' at all, as a translation of 'gehören' in this context. If using 'belong' as a translation, the preposition must be 'to' to keep the same meaning.

Accidentially, the difference between 'belong to' and 'belong in' can be found in the German language as well, between 'gehören zu' and 'gehören in'.

In the phrase in question, 'gehören zu' is used in the meaning 'being a part of'. To express this meaning in English using 'belong', the preposition 'to' must be used as e.g. in 'the house belongs to the property'. Rephrasing this sentence with 'the house belongs in the property' makes it perhaps more obvious that 'in' is misplaced here.

[Merriam-Webster's definition of 'belong in'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belong) is 'to be suitable, appropriate, or advantageous' or 'to be in a proper situation', e.g. 'a dictionary belongs in every home'. The same meaning can in German be expressed, though slightly archaic, with 'gehört in': 'Ein Wörterbuch gehört in jedes Haus.'

To avoid any confusion or ambiguity, I would instead have translated the German phrase 'Islam gehört zu Deutschland' with 'Islam is a part of Germany'.

Comment: Others (Bundeskanzlerin Merkel, for example) have stated the very same idea as "...der Islam ist ein Teil von Deutschland...". I think this makes it very clear that "...belongs in..." is not the best translation.

Comment: Schöner Hintergrundartikel zum Ursprung des Satzes "Der Islam gehört zu Deutschland" http://www.deutschlandradiokultur.de/die-geschichte-eines-satzes-der-islam-gehoert-zu-deutschland.1895.de.html?dram:article_id=308696

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what *the house belongs to the property* means. Perhaps it would be more helpful to choose an example that doesn't run the risk of confusing *gehören + Dat.* with *gehören zu* as it would seem that the aspect of *gehören* at the heart of the issue is precisely that which more closely relates to Besitz or Eigentum.

Comment: @ardila 'The house belongs to the property' means that the house is part of the property. Without chaning the syntax, the meaning could also be to express posession, e.g. 'the house belongs to our neighbour'. The exact meaning of the first example can only be determined by ruling out 'the property is in posession of the house' as a possible meaning, since it does not make sense. Then again, I am not sure myself if I understand the rest of your question.

Comment: @jarnbjo oh, it wasn't a question at all. I was merely commenting on the choice of example to help illustrate the point you were trying to make. I thought that a different sentence which didn't add more ambiguity by introducing yet another aspect of *gehören* (that of property/ownership) would be better suited to your purpose. I still find it  an odd sentence, but it's probably just me then.

Comment: Anybody care to explain the downvote?

Comment: wasn't me, fwiw

Comment: I would translate "belong in" in combination with a big area like a country as "gehört nach ...land". In so far I consider the meaning stronger than *belongs to*, stating it is a misplaced foreign particle.

Comment: @ardila I was using property in the meaning of Grundstück and not Besitz or Eigentum.

Comment: @guidot I disagree. 'Etwas gehört nach <some geographical object>' implies that it is not yet there, but it should be moved to or established there.

Comment: I agree 100%. "is a part of Germany" is the only correct translation in idiomatic English.